# How to use Criteria Queries in Spring Boot Data Jpa Application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an application that uses *Spring Boot Data jpa* .
So far i am using a repository like this

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentEntity, Integer>{
    @Query(value = "" 
        + "SELECT s.studentname "
        + "FROM   studententity s, "
        + "       courseentity c "
        + "WHERE  s.courseid = c.courseid "
        + "       AND s.courseid IN (SELECT c.courseid "
        + "                          FROM   courseentity c "
        + "                          WHERE  c.coursename = ?1)")
    List<String> nameByCourse(String coursename);
}
```

How can i make use of *Criteria Query* that Hibernate provides for such cases in a Spring Boot Application

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [`docs`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)

> To enrich a repository with custom functionality you first define an interface and an implementation for the custom functionality. Use the repository interface you provided to extend the custom interface.

Define an interface like so

```
public interface StudentRepositoryCustom {

    List<String> nameByCourse(String coursename);

}
```

Then define a custom implementation of this interface like so

```
@Service
class StudentRepositoryImpl implements StudentRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<String> nameByCourse(String coursename) {            
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        //Using criteria builder you can build your criteria queries.
    }

}
```

Now you can extend this custom repository implementaion in your JPA repository like so.

```
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<StudentEntity, Integer>, StudentRepositoryCustom {

}
```

Learn more about criteria query and criteria builder [`here`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

Comment: Thanks . But how do we Incorporate Hibernate Criteria Queries over in Spring Boot. Or is there any other Spring Hibernate Jpa kind of thing ?

Comment: can you just explain that once over here like a small eg . will be thankful for this thanks

Comment: You have to get the criteria builder from the `entitymanger` your wired in your custom implementation. Use criteria builder to build your queries. Check out this [link](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria) for detailed explanation about criteria query.

Comment: Can you help me understand with the performance comparison of using criteria and JPQL?

Comment: Is the `@Service` annotation in `StudentRepositoryImpl` correct? Shouldn't it be `@Repository`?

Answer (score 9):

With `Spring-boot-jpa` you are able to use `entityManager` nearly everywhere. The most commom way is to create an own `interface` for custom methods.

```
public interface StudentCustomRepository {

    void anyCustomMethod();
    Student getStudentByName(String name);
}
```

Then implement this interface to a service class where you are able to autowire and use the `entityManager`:

```
@Service
public class StudentCustomRepositoryServiceImpl implements StudentCustomRepository {

     @PersistenceContext
     private EntityManager em;

     @Override
     public void anyCustomMethod(){
         //here use the entityManager
     }

     @Override
     StudentEntity getStudentByName(String name){
         Criteria crit = em.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(StudentEntity.class);
         crit.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
         List<StudentEntity> students = crit.list();
         return students.get(0);
     }
 }
```

You can also decide to implement your `StudentRepository` to your new `StudentCustomRepositoryServiceImpl` class.

Comment: Thanks . But how do we Incorporate Hibernate Criteria Queries over in Spring Boot. Or is there any other Spring Hibernate Jpa kind of thing ?

Comment: @Rahul hibernate is the default persistence provider.

Comment: Yes patrick . But how to get the criteria queries for the same can you just give a samll eg for the above answer u gave

Comment: Why `@Service` instead of `@Repository` in your implementation?

Answer (score 8):

JPA 2 introduces a criteria API that can be used to build queries programmatically.

You can extend a new interface from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends 
  CrudRepository<Customer, Long>, 
  JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer> {

  default List<Customer> findCustomers() {
    return findAll(CustomerSpecs.findCustomers());
  }
```

Then create a customer specs

```java
public final class CustomerSpecs {

    public static Specification<Customer> findCustomers() {
        return new Specification<Customer>() {
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder builder) {

         LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2);
         return builder.lessThan(root.get("birthday"), date);
      }
    };
}
```

The above can be simplified using lambdas as follows

```java
public interface CustomerRepository extends 
  CrudRepository<Customer, Long>, 
  JpaSpecificationExecutor<Customer> {

  default List<Customer> findCustomers() {
    return findAll(
      (root, query, cb) -> {
         LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2);
         return cb.lessThan(root.get("birthday"), date);
      }
    );
  }
```

For more details, refer this spring doc here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: I tried this approach but I get a 404 error when browsing to .../customers/search/findCustomers

Comment: Then it is seems page not found. Is your URL correct ?

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring doc [HibernateTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/HibernateTemplate.html):

> NOTE: Hibernate access code can also be coded in plain Hibernate
>   style. Hence, for newly started projects, consider adopting the
>   standard Hibernate style of coding data access objects instead, based
>   on SessionFactory.getCurrentSession(). This HibernateTemplate
>   primarily exists as a migration helper for Hibernate 3 based data
>   access code, to benefit from bug fixes in Hibernate 4.x.

While according to Hibernate doc:

> New development should focus on the JPA
>   javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery API. Eventually,
>   Hibernate-specific criteria features will be ported as extensions to
>   the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery.

So its better to use JPQL Criteria:[JPA Criteria API Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

Example:

```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
  Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
  q.select(c);
```

where entityManager should be @Autowired. For detail info, see above link

Comment: so how do we use that over here  ? @Afridi

Comment: I have updated my answer(just added a simple example). For more info, follow given link in answer http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Comment: Thanks for the anser

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to [Query creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) into spring data JPA documentation and take a look at the table, JPA give multiple Query creation from method names where you can avoid using a String query