# How I can get entitymanager from crudrepository

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I use Spring Boot and want to improve perfomance. I must download file with 50000 field in database. Use hibernate. I found solution in [Batch inserts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html). But I don't know how get entitymanager from crudrepository

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<OTA, Long>

application.yaml
                jdbc.batch_size: 50
                order_inserts: true
                order_updates: true
                cache.use_second_level_cache: true
```

I creatred MyStorageService and want to save my file:

```
@Service @Repository @Transactional public class MyStorageService {
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    private void insertAll(final List<MyFile> file) {
        myRepository.save(file.getListLine());
    } 

private void insert(final List<OTA> ota) {
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    for (int i = 0; i < ota.size(); i++) {
        session.save(ota.get(i));
        if (i % 50 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
    }

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

}

If use in MyStorageService

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;
```

I get

> ERROR [http-nio-18842-exec-1] JpaTransactionManager: Commit exception
>   overridden by rollback exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Transaction not active    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.getRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.isRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:665)
>
> ERROR [http-nio-18842-exec-1] JpaTransactionManager: Commit exception
>   overridden by rollback exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Transaction not active    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.getRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.isRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:665)

If

@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

I get

> ERROR [http-nio-18842-exec-5] JpaTransactionManager: Commit exception
>   overridden by rollback exception java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Transaction not active    at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.getRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.isRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:665)
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.clear(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1382)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.clear(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:554)

I use base method `save`from crud repository, but want to improve perfomance and use insert. Tell me please how get entitymanager from crudrepository.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot - configure EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074547/spring-boot-configure-entitymanager)

Comment: [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44278901/3493036)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure of how your spring configuration is set. With a hope this might help, here you go:

If you have set up a bean of `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` in your context xml or @Configuration java file, in that case, you can acquire the entity manager in the following way.

Assume that you declared the above one as follows:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceRefToBeMentioned"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="package.to.be.mentioned"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJPAVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Now in your service class, you can Autowire the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean as below.

```
@Autowired
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;
```

In your method, where you want to get access to entity manager, you can do as below:

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager();
```

After this, the below code would follow:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
....
...
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

However, make sure you close the entityManager after you are done with the whole transaction, like below:

```
entityManager.close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad, it helped.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view there are several potential problems.

- @Service and [@Repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html) are both stereotype annotations and allows Spring to autodetect annotated classes and to register within a context. The difference is class thus annotated with @Repository is eligible for Spring DataAccessException translation when used in conjunction with a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.
- If you annotated class with [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) you need to make sure that CGLIB is present in your classpath because Spring AOP requires it to create a proxy for classes.
- Private methods are not accessible by Spring AOP that means when you annotated class with @Transactional it's methods are not within a transactional context

So I'd suggest to separate concerns e.g. remove unnecessary annotations like @Service and @Transactional if you want to manage transaction by yourself, however according to your code it's not necessary unless you will commit within a for loop after each batch complete.

Answer (score 0):

Just autowire EntityManager

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work for my case. I updated my question