# spring boot - datasource not returning used connections

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm using spring boot with hibernate on PostgreSQL.

> DB: PostgreSQL version : 9.6.8
>
> SPRING-boot version :

[image: SPRING-boot version]

**My Problem:**

> After two request GET calls , the connections are not available from
> pool(or new one).

Can some one point out what went wrong?
So Below exception is thrown

```
    java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 3000ms.
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:667) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 3000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:667) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:183) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:148) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
```

I have set below connection pool properties

```
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=250
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=3000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=500
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=3000
```

DAO class:

```
    @Component
public class NickNameDAO {


    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    
    
    @Transactional
    public List<NickName> getUserDetails() {
        
        
        
        SessionFactory session = AutoWiringUtils.getSessionFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        
        Criteria criteria = session.openSession().createCriteria(NickName.class);
        List<NickName> returnValues = criteria.list();
        return returnValues;
    }
    
    
}
```

Controller Class:

```
public class MainController {
@GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<NickName> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return nickNameService.getUserDetails();
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class NickNameService {
    
    @Autowired
    private NickNameDAO nickNameDAO;
    
    public  List<NickName> getUserDetails() {
        return nickNameDAO.getUserDetails();

    }

}
```

session creater class

```
public class AutoWiringUtils {
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        
        
         
        if (entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class) == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("factory is not a hibernate factory");
        }
        return entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

**Update :1**

When using `session.getCurrentSession` I'm facing below exception

```
@Component
public class NickNameDAO {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    
    @Transactional
    public List<NickName> getUserDetails() {
        SessionFactory session = AutoWiringUtils.getSessionFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(NickName.class);
        List<NickName> returnValues = criteria.list();
        return returnValues;
    }
}
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3466) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1422) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:147) ~[spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: That is some mess! You are using @Transactional annotation opening a transation with the entityManager and then opening a session unwrapping the entityManagerFactory! just choose one for the sake of that poor connection pooler

Comment: e.g. if you want to use criteria just remove the @Transactional (that is spring data jpa) and dont create an entity manager (jpa) at all and just unwrap the Session (hibernate specific) from the emf

Comment: ok then  can you help how to get SessionFactory without creating entity manager.

Comment: SessionFactory session = AutoWiringUtils.getSessionFactory(entityManagerFactory);
is fine just dont get the EntityManager  or begin the trasnaction with it em.getTransaction().begin()

Comment: updated .. now running out of connections after 5 calls.

Comment: Well no because you are opening sessions yourself. Why have you made that contraption? Just use the `EntityManager` or at least never use `openSession` but use `getCurrentSession` . However imho you shouldn't be messing around with the plain Hibernate API at all.

Comment: @M.Deinum update the question , I tried to use getCurrentSession  and I'm facing exception

Comment: Which indicates you are missing a setting in your configuration. But why are you using the plain Hibernate API in the first place. Instead just use plain JPA.

Comment: how can i query criteria without SessionFactory object? I tried to follow this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278066/how-to-use-criteria-queries-in-spring-boot-data-jpa-application)

Comment: @theRoot https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Comment: @Zeromus seems criteria is depreciated . Thanks will try to use your link