# Spring data mongo in condition case insensitive

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, case-insensitive

I've got objects with string field and i want to search all objects which fits (case insensitive) to my array with string list.

e.g.

```
public class Person { 
   private String name;
}

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("teSt1", "tEsT2");
```

i can create condition like:

```
Criteria.where("name").in(list);
```

but i have no idea how to make it case insensitive (connect it with regex)

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you are extending `CrudRepository` you can try to create a method called `findByNameInIgnoreCase(List<String> names)`

Comment: thanks for reply, i found that but it's not solution, it's only part of method, there is also criteria for keyword etc

Comment: Have a look at this useful answers about `criteria` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44278901/8112217 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44278967/8112217

Answer (score 1):

I think it's impossible to build it that way

```
db.getCollection('collection').find( { "field" : { "$in" : [{"$regex": '...', "$options": "i"}] } })
```

query like that returns error, i figured out solution which is very very not optimal, but works. Just build regex criteria for all list values and connect it with OR, like:

```
Criteria orCriteria = new Criteria();
Criteria[] regExList = new Criteria[list.size()];   
IntStream.range(0, list.size()).forEach(i -> {
    regExList[i] = Criteria.where("field").regex(list.get(i), "i");
});

orCriteria.orOperator(regExList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a list of Pattern instead of the strings in the in() method to achieve this.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



Criteria.where("name").in(list.stream().map(s->Pattern.compile(s,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In case you would like an exact match and not a like search, you can try something like this.

```
Criteria.where("name").in(list.stream().map(s->Pattern.compile("^"+s+"$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

This adds the regex of starts with and ends with, which makes it an exact match with case insensitiveness.